# include header and footer not working with ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs, viewengine

I'm new to js in general and trying to implement a simple ejs page using header and footer template. I followed the instruction from https://ejs.co/ but the header.ejs and footer.ejs are not successfully added into my list.ejs page

My code for list.ejs

```
<%- include('header'); -%>
    <div class="box" id="heading">
        <h1>
            <%= listTitle %>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <% for(let i=0; i<newListItem.length; i++){ %>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>
                    <%= newListItem[i] %>
                </p>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <form class="item" action="/" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" name="list" value=<%=listTitle %>>+</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<%- include('footer'); -%>
```

My header.ejs

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>    
<body>
```

My footer ejs

```
</body>
    <footer>
        copy right info
    </footer>

</html>
```

In my main app.js I already included app.set("view engine", 'ejs'). The views folder include: app.js, header.ejs, footer.ejs, list.ejs

Comment: You did put the footer after the body tag, is that intentional?